# Getting null from viewController obtained from Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I'm new to storyboards. Any ideas why this might happen? 
When I fire 'test' from a button within the containing view controller the log shows vc1 (as expected)
However when I 'fire' test2 from another viewController I get null..

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic)  UIViewController *vc1;

- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"log %@", _vc1 );
}

- (void)test2 {
NSLog(@"log %@", _vc1 );
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
_vc1 =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test1"];
}
```

Comment: You probably call test2 before viewDidLoad is called, meaning _vc1 isn't set (so is nil, which logs as '(null)') when you try to log _vc1.

Comment: Nope.. 2013-06-08 15:39:35.622 viewDidLoad

2013-06-08 15:39:37.957  log (null)   viewDidLoad gets fired first. I'm baffled!

Comment: Your `other viewcontroller` probably has a different instance of your current VC, one that maybe isn't loaded visually? Otherwise try your `viewDidLoad` code in `viewWillAppear` &/or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Which controller is that viewDidLoad method in? The same controller as test2?

Comment: I think I am narrowing it down I checked the id from this class (self) and the object I was calling test2 on... and they were different.

Comment: The UIViewController above is being instantiated by a Container View in Storyboard. But I was getting an instance of this UIViewController in the calling object by instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. Thats my issue for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like test2 is in vc1, just do exactly as you do in vc1 in vc2

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am doing [aViewController test2] from another object and getting null. However when I access the log via 'test' (fired from a UIButton which 'aViewController' contains ) it works as expected.

Comment: Is the button (thats not working) located in a separate UIViewController than test2 is located in. If so, how are you accessing its methods? I'm confused how you are setting this up. Please post more code or explain your view controler"s" better